# Why it's asked to move mouse over blank area while generating key in putty gen?

Tags: putty

Recently I installed putty gen for my windows, and while generating a key, something like this appeared:

[image]

Asking me to move the mouse over the blank area.

I know it may sound trivial, but I was curious to know what actually happens behind the scenes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

To generate an encryption key, you need random data.

You have to get the random data from somewhere, and if you generate it with a computer algorithm that doesn't take external input it will be more predictable.

Windows [takes user input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/bringup/uefi-entropy-gathering-protocol?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as random data to compensate.